# how to set image width/height equal to wrapping DIV after rotation?

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, css-transforms

I have an image inside a `DIV`

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="testimg" src="http://www.dothetest.co.uk/images/do-test.gif" alt="Test" />
</div>
```

Image perfectly fits into the DIV(i am using border to highlight it)

```
#wrapper{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:250px;
    height:292px;
}
#wrapper img{

    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Now if i apply  `-webkit-transform :rotate(90deg)`  then after rotation image goes out the parent `DIV` but i want that image should again fit to parent's DIV size.

I tried to set the .width() & .height() using jQuery but it doesn't work. So pleas suggest how can i do this?

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FcQZm/

Comment: Width and height invert when you rotate it 90 deg.  That is, you need to swap the values to keep it the same dimensions.

Comment: CSS doesn't really pick up the changes when the image rotates, the dimensions are still the same. In other words, the widht and height properties of the image doesn't really match with what you see on the screen, so you manually have to change that to whatever fits. The width and height are of course reversed, but the offset gets shifted too, so you have to adjust that as well, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FcQZm/1/) here !

Comment: why don't you rotate the wrapper instead? Also, you should include the none-prefixed version.